# How to deduplicate files when storing in the SDFS file system using OpenDedup

Tags: filesystems, deduplication

I followed the link, http://www.opendedup.org/quickstart for
installing OpenDedup in my linux machine (Ubuntu 12.04 - 64 bit). I created a SDFS volume and
mounted it.

I copied two similar Ubuntu VMs, which has a high amount of sharing,
into the SDFS volume. But the files got stored as such. Is there any
specific commands for enabling deduplicaiton feature in the SDFS
volume. Or will dedpulication get applied to the files that we copy
into the volume.?